# Creating DataTable with inner join query on DataSet

Tags: mysql, datatable, dataset, inner-join

i'm having a small issue on trying to create a datatable with the following query:

```
SELECT sp_sales_data.productname, sp_sales_data.quantity, sp_sales_data.tax_percent, sp_sales_data.finalprice,
sp_sales.date, sp_stores.location, sp_sales.change, sp_sales.ammountreceived, sp_sales.totaltopay,
sp_users.FirstName, sp_users.LastName, sp_company_data.logo, sp_company_data.maincity, sp_company_data.name, sp_company_data.mainzipcode, sp_company_data.nif, sp_company_data.phone
FROM sp_sales_data 
INNER JOIN sp_sales
ON sp_sales_data.sale_id = sp_sales.id
INNER JOIN sp_users
ON sp_sales.client = sp_users.id
INNER JOIN sp_stores
ON sp_sales.store = sp_stores.id
INNER JOIN sp_company_data
ON sp_company_data.id = '1'
```

it reports me the following problem:
error in select clause : expression near DATE
missing from clause.
unable to parse query text

the preview works just fine but the tableadapter is still empty

Comment: `date` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html), try qoute it with backticks `\`date\``.

Comment: is there a workaround of it? or i need to change the column name?

Comment: No date is not reserved word , its something else, what is the error code from mysql ?

Comment: i changed the column to data instead of date, and it worked @AbhikChakraborty